# explode a row of spark dataset into several rows with added column using flatmap

Tags: scala, apache-spark, explode, flatmap

I have a DataFrame with the following schema :

```
root
 |-- journal: string (nullable = true)
 |-- topicDistribution: vector (nullable = true)
```

The `topicDistribution` field is a vector of doubles: [0.1, 0.2 0.15 ...]

What I want is is to explode each row into several rows to obtain the following schema:

```
root
 |-- journal: string
 |-- topic-prob: double // this is the value from the vector
 |-- topic-id : integer // this is the index of the value from the vector
```

To clarify, I've created a case class:

```
case class JournalDis(journal: String, topic_id: Integer, prob: Double)
```

I've managed to achieve this using dataset.explode in a very awkward way:

```
val df1 = df.explode("topicDistribution", "topic") {
    topics: DenseVector => topics.toArray.zipWithIndex
}.select("journal", "topic")
val df2 = df1.withColumn("topic_id", df1("topic").getItem("_2")).withColumn("topic_prob", df1("topic").getItem("_1")).drop(df1("topic"))
```

But **dataset.explode is deprecated**. I wonder how to achieve this using `flatmap` method?

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but should work:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector

df.as[(String, Vector)].flatMap { 
  case (j, ps) => ps.toArray.zipWithIndex.map { 
    case (p, ti) => JournalDis(j, ti, p)
  }
}
```

Comment: Error:(38, 20) Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
    val df1 = df.as[(String, DenseVector)].flatMap {

Comment: The signature of flatMap:

Comment: def
flatMap[U](func: (T) ⇒ TraversableOnce[U])(implicit arg0: Encoder[U]): Dataset[U]
 Permalink
(Scala-specific) Returns a new Dataset by first applying a function to all elements of this Dataset, and then flattening the results.

Comment: Did you `import spark.implicits._ `?

Comment: No, I didn't import spark.implicits._